# Embed a whole shopify store inside a iframe

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I would ideally like to embed a whole shopify store inside an iframe to allow the full browsing/purchasing/checkout process inside another website (and mobile app, using a webview).

I know there are various JavaScript integration options but they all seem to require basically building the store yourself.

"Buy" buttons won't cut it because the user needs to be able to create a cart and easily add multiple products then checkout.

I note that shopify website disables embedding in iframe using `content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'none';`

Is there some way to just embed the whole store inside my WebApp, using iframe or some other approach?

Comment: You can't use the Shopify website inside iframe due to Shopify restrictions, you can use the headless approach to create a new frontend experience for website visitors.